# How can I animate from left to right the searchbar in a searchdisplaycontroller?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'd like to animate the search bar from left to right in the navigation bar of a `SearchDisplayController`, as seen in the *Periscope* app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most probably a custom implementation. You can implement the functionality yourself. You just need to add a textfield and reload the tableview with the appropriate content whenever the text in the textfield changes.